# How to delete input field if I click on button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, lit-element

I have a form with an input field that works in this way:

If someone write something and then click on the "add" button near the input field, that "something" is added to a list of elements below.

```
<input type="text" name="_element" placeholder='Type something' @change=${this.onPropChange} required>
<button type="button" name="element" @click=${this.onChange}>Add</button>
```

List of elements:

```
<div>
   ${this.value.elements && this.value.elements.map((element) => {
        return html`
                  <li>
                    <span class="label" style = "font-weight: bold;">Element: </span>
                    <span>${element}</span>
                  </li>
        ` 
     })
   } 
</div>
```

onChange function:

```
onChange(e) {
        
        switch (e.target.getAttribute('name')){
            case '_element':
            this._element = e.target.value;
            break;
            case 'element':

              this.value = {...this.value, elements: [...this.value.elements||'']};
              this.value.elements.push(this._element);
              this._element='';
                         
            break;
   }
}
```

I'd like that when someone click on "add" button, the "something" written in the input field is cleared.
I can't use submit button or input type = submit".

Does it exist a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your onChange function to find the input field and set its placeholder value to `''` empty string each time you hit the button.

Set an id into your input tag like:

```
<input id='input_field' type="text" name="_element" placeholder='Type something' @change=${this.onPropChange} required>
```

Extending your onChange function like this might help, if I got you right:

```
const element = document.getElementById('input_field');
element.value = '';
```

Comment: I tried to do it, but it gives me an error in console, that const is equal to null or undefined. I think that it depends on page render... I really don't know

Comment: Sorry for replying that late :/ Can you try to console.log only 'document'? Maybe something in general with your setup is wrong.

Comment: Also, maybe try to write it in pure js with a button like https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp to trigger the function.